# Windows 8.1 VPN connection not deletable

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn

something is really wrong with my Windows 8. I have a VPN connection for my company that can't be deleted.

I can also not add any new VPN connections. And when I try to connect to the one configured it just hangs. Not even the username password input fiellds are opening.

What could cause this?  The only thing I recently changed was turning off Hyper-V because VirtualBox has problems with Hyper-V beeing turned on.

Any clue?

Comment: When you attempt to delete the VPN connection, what happens exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound dialogue opens if I want to delete the connection and then it closes and nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried deleting the connection in both PC Settings and Network Connections (more [info](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/47188-virtual-private-network-connection-delete-windows-8-1-a.html))?  Another way is to go to "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk" and delete the file "rasphone.pbk" (better keep a backup).

Comment: @harrymc when I delete it in PC Settings it is removed. Then if I reopen it is still there and I can't delete it. I can't even delete it in Network Connections. I do not have a Microsoft folder under \Roaming

Comment: Check for hidden folders under Roaming. Try checking Windows integrity by using [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html). Just in case, do also some antivirus scans by at least a couple of such products.

Comment: I did a sfc /scannow yesterday. Nothing suspicious. Or anything I could follow. Found the folder _hiddenPBK with "rasphone.pbk" in it and delted it. Still there. And I got a message RAS Service could not be started

Comment: Typing "vpn" at the Start screen supposedly lets one remove VPN connections (see [this article](http://david.gardiner.net.au/2013/09/windows-81-vpn-settings.html)). Check also for [broken miniports](http://www.lukebrowning.com/sysadmin/windows/windows-81-vpn-connection-freezefailure/), where the [Wan miniport repair tool](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/index.php/clanky/wan-miniport-repair-tool-solve-vpn-and-dial-up-error-code-720-and-similar-ppperrors.html) could be useful.

Comment: @harrymc thx. The broken miniports seemed to be it. Used the repairt tool and everything works again. Now if you form an answer I can reward you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is explained in the article
[Windows 8.1 VPN Connection Freeze/Failure](http://www.lukebrowning.com/sysadmin/windows/windows-81-vpn-connection-freezefailure/) :

> I had a problem recently on Windows 8.1 where trying to create a VPN
>   connection would just cause the Windows interface to freeze and no
>   connection made. After clicking connect, a number of different WAN
>   Miniport adapters appear in Device manager under Network adapters
>   (they may also be visible by clicking View > Show hidden devices) with
>   yellow exclamation marks. They are mostly different types of VPN
>   connections such as PPTP and L2TP. The way to fix them is to uninstall
>   and then reinstall the devices - unfortunately, they aren't as easy to
>   remove as normal devices and do not allow you to uninstall.

One way for fixing a miniport is to change its driver, thus converting it
to a device that can be removed:

> 1. Open Device Manager and expand Network adapters (maybe needs Show hidden devices).
> 2. Right click on the non-working miniport and choose "Update Driver".
> 3. Choose "Browse my computer".
> 4. On the next page, choose "Let me pick driver from a list".
> 5. Uncheck "Show compatible hardware".
> 6. From the Manufacturer list, select "Microsoft", and from the "Network Adapter" list choose any driver that will allow it to be
>      uninstalled (example "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter").
> 7. Now you can right click on the device it just created and click uninstall.

One can also do the above much easier by using the
[Wan miniport repair tool](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/index.php/clanky/wan-miniport-repair-tool-solve-vpn-and-dial-up-error-code-720-and-similar-ppperrors.html) (try version 2 first) :

> How to use it (Windows 8):
>
> 1. run [Wan miniport repair](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/wan-miniport-repair-x64.exe) tool (or [version 2](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/wan-miniport-repair-v2-x64.exe))
> 2. restart computer
> 3. run [Wan miniport installer](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/wan-miniport-install-x64.exe)
> 4. restart computer and enjoy fully working Dial-up and VPN access again.
>
> Manual for Windows 8.1:
>
> 1. run [version 2](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/wan-miniport-repair-v2-x64.exe)
> 2. restart computer
> 3. click 'network' icon and and wait a few minutes. Other steps shouldn't be necessary.
>
> If You still use 32-bit Windows, use following links: [Wan miniport
>   repair tool (32bit)](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/wan-miniport-repair-x86.exe) (or [version 2 (32bit)](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/wan-miniport-repair-v2-x86.exe)) and [Wan miniport
>   installer (32bit)](https://www.vpnhosting.cz/wan-miniport-install-x86.exe).

Comment: Worth linking to [KB2871372](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2871372).